# Creating a tournament bracket using linked lists

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to create a tournament bracket using linked lists where each match of the tournament is a node that has 2 parent nodes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about linked list. I think you need a class Team and a class Match. The match will have 2 fields, Team1 and Team2, a field round (top 16, top8 etc) and a field NextMatch that is an instance of Match, which will be the next round. All these Matches could be placed inside an ArrayList. Or this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you are describing is a tree, not a list.

While it is theoretically possible to use as list to model an array, and then use the array to model an arbitrary data structure, the result would be a complicated, inefficient mess.

A better idea would be model the matches using a custom `Match` class; e.g. something like this:

```
  public class Match {
      private Player player1;
      private Player player2;
      private Match leadupMatch1; // null in first round
      private Match leadupMatch2; // null in first round
      private Match winnersMatch;
      private Match losersMatch;  // if needed
      private Result result;
      ...
  }

  public class Player {
      ...
  }

  public enum Result {
      NONE,
      PLAYER_1_WINS,
      PLAYER_2_WINS
  }
```